# Redirecting folders to their corresponding subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, subdomain

Trying to configure apache via .htaccess so **any folder** will be redirected **to the corresponding subdomain**:

Example:

> Original URL: http://zipcode.is/ro/010011
>   redirects to: http://ro.zipcode.direct/010011

Moving the folder from zipcode.is/**ro**/010011 to a subdirectory on the new domain: **ro**.zipcode.direct/010011 (note that the domain is different as well). Now this is working but as soon as I change the country ISO code, it won't work any more e.g. **zipcode.is/us/10128**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/(\d+)$ http://$1.zipcode.direct/$2 [R=301,L]
```

the above was the best and shortest solution *(thanks Ruslan G.!)*, the first method by *Alexey S.* doesn't check types and was less elegant, left it in case someone wants to further tweak:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ http://$1.zipcode.direct/$2 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ http://$1.zipcode.direct [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule inside site root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!subdomains/).*)$ subdomains/%1/$1 [L,NC]
```